# ImportError: No Module named twitter - MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, twitter, package, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to run a python program with twitter module. 
I installed the twitter and json packages via:

```
pip install twitter
pip install simplejson
```

While running the program I'm getting error in both python 2 and python 3 version.

My code:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
import twitter
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 5, in <module>
    import twitter
ImportError: No module named 'twitter'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get this error in the Terminal ?
If no, try to open the Terminal and run python then import twitter.

Maybe you can try to use pip3 with Python3

First install pip3 then run :

```
pip3 install twitter
```

And run again the import in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced this issue:
- un-install below packages (twitter, python_twitter).
   **pip uninstall twitter
   pip uninstall python_twitter**

Then install Twitter.
   **pip install twitter**

problem will solve.